# Can I simplify this Rust code dealing with Option<T> and Result<T>?

Tags: error-handling, rust, option-type

I'm working on my first actual Rust program, a custom i3status. It's coming along nicely, but there's two places where I have to deal with `Result<T>` and `Option<T>` and the code looks really ugly, leading me to believe that I've missed some language feature or library function for writing these parts more cleanly.

[This is the file in question](https://github.com/majewsky/rust-i3status/blob/aebb39ee948c04a95d4154a79ce69455cf215a58/src/providers/battery.rs), but I'll quote the relevant parts here. The first one is this:

```
fn read_number_from_file(path: &str) -> Option<i64> {
    let mut file = match File::open(path) {
        Ok(f) => f,
        Err(_) => return None,
    };
    let mut contents = String::new();
    match file.read_to_string(&mut contents) {
        Ok(_) => {},
        Err(_) => return None,
    };
    match contents.trim().parse::<i64>() {
        Ok(val) => Some(val),
        Err(_) => None,
    }
}
```

Swallowing error messages here is intentional. An i3status does not have an stderr, so all I can do is skip rendering of the broken parts.

Regardless of that, this code looks ugly, with its repeated use of `match` to discard `Err` values. I tried to use the new `?` operator by making the return type a `std::io::Result<i64>`, but `str::parse` returns a different type of error, so that doesn't work AFAICS. I therefore went with `Option<i64>` as the lowest common denominator.

The second ugly part is where this function gets used:

```
let energy_full = match read_number_from_file(ENERGY_FULL_PATH) {
    Some(val) => val,
    None      => return Vec::new(),
};
let energy_now = match read_number_from_file(ENERGY_NOW_PATH) {
    Some(val) => val,
    None      => return Vec::new(),
};
let is_charging = match read_number_from_file(POWER_ONLINE_PATH) {
    Some(val) => val > 0,
    None      => return Vec::new(),
};
```

I feel like one should be able to contract each of the `match` expressions into a function call like `.or_else()`, but `.or_else(|| return Vec::new())` obviously won't work since the `return` is scoped to the lambda instead of the original function.

So, in both cases, my question is whether I can replace `match` by something more compact and idiomatic.

Comment: Even if `STDERR` is not visible by default you still should log errors to it.  They might even end up in `~/.xsession-errors`... If you fear it might get noisy you could use `debug!` from the `log` crate and friends.

Comment: `.xsession-errors` won't help since I'm actually using Sway (i.e. Wayland instead of X11), but you gave me the idea of looking if Sway connects a useful stderr to the status_command process.

Comment: Shouldn't you give it a unique name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To combine `Option<T>`s with `Result<T, E>`s, use [`ok()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.ok) and the question mark operator:

```
fn read_number_from_file(path: &str) -> Option<i64> {
    let mut file = File::open(path).ok()?;
    let mut contents = String::new();
    file.read_to_string(&mut contents).ok()?;
    contents.trim().parse::<i64>().ok()
}
```

As for the second part of the question, if you can contain all those variable bindings in a single function:

```
fn foo() -> Option<Vec<i64>> { // or some other Option<Vec>
    let energy_full = read_number_from_file(ENERGY_FULL_PATH)?;
    let energy_now = read_number_from_file(ENERGY_NOW_PATH)?;
    let is_charging = read_number_from_file(POWER_ONLINE_PATH)? > 0;

    Some(Vec::new()) // placeholder for the valid return value
}
```

You can then use [`unwrap_or_else()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or_else) on its result to return an empty `Vec` upon any error:

```
let foo = foo().unwrap_or_else(|| vec![]);
```

Or just [`unwrap_or()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or), because [empty vectors don't allocate memory](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#guarantees):

```
let foo = foo().unwrap_or(vec![]);
```

Comment: For the second part we can move all the code into a new function `fn new_func(...) -> Option<Vec<Something>>` and old function will do `new_func(...).unwrap_or_else(||vec![])` [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1d29f6ab2e18fc81e4084df2f31f0c36&version=stable)

Comment: @red75prime answer updated; thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: By the way, `unwrap(vec![])` is as good as `unwrap_or_else`, since an empty vector doesn't allocate.

Comment: @aochagavia you mean `unwrap_or(vec![])`, right? Sure, I can include this information.

Comment: @ljedrz yes, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2):

For the second part, you can use one of the comprehension crates available on crates.io like [map_for](https://crates.io/crates/map_for), [comp](https://crates.io/crates/comp) or [mdo](https://crates.io/crates/mdo). For example with `map_for`:

```
return map_for!(
    energy_full  <- read_number_from_file(ENERGY_FULL_PATH);
    energy_now   <- read_number_from_file(ENERGY_NOW_PATH);
    power_online <- read_number_from_file(POWER_ONLINE_PATH);
    is_charging  = power_online > 0;
    => vec![ energy_full, energy_now ]
).unwrap_or_else (|| vec![]);
```

Full disclosure: I am the author of the `map_for` crate.